# setText not displaying value

Tags: android, textview

One of my textViews is not being adjusted when I call the function:

```
public void wordList() {
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         TextView lv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listText);
         lv.setText("Text");
}
```

Here's the xml:
If I add android:text="Text" to the xml it works.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background ="#268496" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prefixText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="12pt"
        android:typeface="sans" />

     <EditText
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="12pt"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    </LinearLayout>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="12pt"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: default background color is white

Comment: Could you post broader code?

Comment: Is your XML valid? You don't seem to have a root node.

Comment: How are you calling `wordList()`? Have you verified that the function is ran?

Comment: My background is turquoise, you can see the first TextView. My code is over 200 lines, I'm setting up the first textView in the same manner and it works. The XML is valid. I added print statements to make sure the method is ran.

Comment: Do you call `setContentView()` anywhere else, particularly, after this method?

Comment: Just played around with it. setContentView is the problem. I also call it when I'm assigning the first textView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `setContentView()` after running it here then it will overwrite this call and set the content to its default (what's in the xml). If you call `setContentView()` say in `onCreate()` then you don't need to call it again as long as the `TextView` is inside that xml.

So, call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` then call your function

```
 wordList();
```

then

```
public void wordList() {
     TextView lv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listText);
     lv.setText("Text");
}
```

Comment: Just calling it in the onCreate is causing me other problems. I need to figure out where to call it. I'm on the right track.

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem calling in `onCreate()` but I don't know what you have. Just make sure you call it before trying to initialize any `Views` in the `layout`. If you can't figure it out then post a new question with relevant code and errors

Answer (score 1):

You have white color of textview's text. So if the background color is white, then you just don't see it.

Comment: The OP stated that the background is not white. Also, if that were the case then the OP wouldn't see anything when setting the text in xml

Comment: The background is android:background ="#268496". Not white.

Comment: @codeMagic  android:background ="#268496" for the relative layout and for textview android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

Comment: @Raghunandan yes but if that was the problem then it wouldn't show when setting text in xml which the OP said worked

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything "wrong" in your posted example. The kinds of things that may be in play here are:

a) is your `TextView` within the visible area (hard code some text to see if it shows up)

b) are  you sure you're calling the method that sets the text?

c) do you have some other overlapping ID somewhere else that is confusing this process?

It has to be something like that.

Comment: its something to do with setContentView, I removed it from this method and kept it during setText of my first textView and it worked

Comment: sure... that's exactly what I'm talking about.